# Deserialization not setting default value for a value type property on null response for that field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json-deserialization

I will take an example to explain my issue.

JSON response

```
{
  "SomeDate": "2023-01-01T12:00:00"
}
```

My C# Model

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; } // Non-nullable int
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
    // Other properties...
}
```

My C# code for deserializing the `jsonString` which contains the response.

```
ResponseModel response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(jsonString);

Console.WriteLine(response.SomeNumber); 
Console.WriteLine(response.SomeDate);
```

Instead of outputting `0` for the field `SomeNumber` it throws the error `Null object cannot be converted to a value type`.

On making the field `SomeNumber` as `?` (nullable) it works and sets it to `null`.

According to what I have learned if the JSON response contains a null value for a field, and the corresponding property in your C# model is a non-nullable value type, the deserialization process should set the property to its default value.

My question is if it is not set as a nullable property shouldn't the deserializer set the `int` field `SomeNumber` to its default value `0` instead of throwing an error?

Comment: i test your code and [it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnfhz.png) out of the box without any proplem in `.NET7` & `.NET8` with newtensoftJson `13.0.3` also with `System.Text.Json` no Exaption Throw